# SMS activity within a Journey

Tags: journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms, sendsmsactivity

I have a Journey that uses a filtered Data Extension as the source from the Master DE. The Journey includes three emails, and I want the first email to be sent at the same time as an SMS message. I'm wondering if I need to create a separate DE specifically for the mobile field, locale, and subscriber key (SK), or if I can use the activity within the Journey to send the SMS message to the existing Data Source I already have?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the contacts will already have a reliable Mobile number assocated with their contact record, you can select "Use mobile number attribute from Contacts" in Journey Settings (see image for more clarity).
[image]

If not then you will have to select the "Use phone number attribute from Entry Source" option and ensure you have a Mobile Number field in you Journey Source DE. You will of course also need a subscriberkey. You do not need to include "Locale" for Journey Builder SMS's though.